# How do I set up DNS, AWS S3, AWS Cloudfront, and AWS Certificate Manager to secure multiple sites

Tags: dns, certificate, https, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to secure multiple static AWS S3 websites delivered via AWS Cloudfront CDN with one certificate.

[This AWS article says I should be able to do this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-limits.html#cnames-and-https-same-certificate-multiple-distributions), but it's not working.

One is a web-app, the other is a web-site for marketing the web-app.

You will notice below that most of the settings are the same. The CNAME settings in Cloudfrount CDN and GoDaddy DNS are basically all that are different.

```
Certificate settings / details:

 - Domain name: mydomain.us
 - Additional names: *.mydomain.us
 - Validation status: Success
 - Associated resources: arn:aws:cloudfront::[accountkey]:distribution/[CDN1] & same/[CDN2]
```

.

```
CDN 1 (web-app) settings:

 - Origin = web-app.s3.amazonaws.com
 - CNAMEs = *.mydomain.us
 - SSL Cert = mydomain.us
 - Domain name = [app].cloudfront.net

DNS 1 (web-app) settings:

 - CNAME = * | [app].cloudfront.net

*Site 1 (the web-app) successfully loads secured in HTTPS.

 - app.mydomain.us, custom.mydomain.us, etc.
```

.

```
CDN 2 (web-site) settings:

 - Origin = web-site.s3.amazonaws.com
 - CNAMEs = www.mydomain.us and web.mydomain.us
 - SSL Cert = mydomain.us
 - Domain name = [site].cloudfront.net
 - All other settings such as security policy, HTTP versions, viewer protocol policy and everything I can see are the same as CDN 1.

DNS 2 (web-site) settings:

 - CNAME = web | [site].cloudfront.net

 - CNAME = www | [site].cloudfront.net

 *Site 2 (the web-site) does not load secured 

 - web.mydomain.us or www.mydomain.us
```

All S3 settings are identical, less a CORS policy for the web-app so I can GET resources hosted at app.mydomain.us from custom.mydomain.us.

What do I need to change to enable this to work properly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *"Site 2 (the web-site) does not load secured"*  What are you saying, here?  It loads as http and doesn't redirect to https?  Or is there an error?

Comment: The simplest option may be to simply get a new certificate that covers e.g. `www.mydomain.us` and `web.mydomain.us`, then use it just for your website. [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com) offers completely free certificates from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org). The only downside is they have to renewed every 3 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel silly for not figuring this out before spending so much time researching an answer and writing this detailed question. I mentioned that the viewer protocol policies were the same, but that didn't make them right. I found, in the AWS Cloudfront CDN distribution settings, that my viewer protocol was HTTP and HTTPS.

The viewer protocol policy in distribution behaviors must be **Redirect HTTP to HTTPS** to get the behavior I am seeking.

Thanks for your comments.